# Ruby on Rails -- new install on windows 7 but cant run ruby commands, problem with path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-7, installation

I just installed ruby on rails on my new computer ( I was using instantrails before) and I'm trying to get everything setup.

Im running Windows 7. So I followed the instructions from this tutorial.

http://blogupstairs.com/ruby-on-rails/installing-ruby-on-rails-on-windows-7/

The problem i'm guessing is step 3

"Add the newly installed bin directory to your path in your windows system : Open windows explorer-> right click the icon computer-> choose Properties -> in the contol panel Home, Click Advanced system settings and then click Envitonment Variables button->in the system variables click new and add new system variables like this :  Variable name : RUBY_HOME  , Variable Value : C:\Ruby, after that add it in to the path and add the bin after a semicolon to the “Path” variable like this : C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\AGL;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%RUBY_HOME%\bin"

I set created the system variables but when I try to run script/generate in the main directory of my app I get the error

"Ruby: no such file or directory --script/generate"

I checked the apps directory and the script folder is in there.  How can I run the "ruby script/generate" commands from the control panel?

I was guessing it was something with the path but I dont know any ways to check to find out whats going wrong.

Comment: Did you add `C:\Ruby19\bin;` to path? What say `path` and `ruby -v` commands?

Comment: Hopefully the path to the Ruby installation does not contain spaces? Also, why not use the Ruby Installer: http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Rails 3.0+? In this version of rails and up, the script/* folder has been deprecated in favor of `rails generate`, `rails server`, etc. See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure `gem install rails` now installs 3 by default, so the tutorial is a bit out of date. You can double check with `gem list rails`.

Answer (score 0):

In 99.99999% of all cases, if a computer tells you that it cannot find a file at a specific location, it is because that file is not at that specific location.

So, *is* there actually a file named `generate` in a directory named `script` in the current directory?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently installed RoR on my "clean" Win7 as well.

What IDE are you using?

I suggest trying [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) with NetBeans/RubyMine:

- JRuby installer does all the work (even adds the proper variables to your `path` in *system environment settings*...,
- IDEs take care of **gems**, setting up **servers** etc.

As for the commands, as *Nuclearsandwitch* mentioned, there is no `script/generate` or `script/server` in Rails 3. **Just make sure you in the directory with your Rails** app and then try running `rails server`. It should work :-)